# Possible DRY with Pausing Mechanism

Tags: c#, design, concurrency, gui, state

**Background**

I am currently working on the architecture for a future software design. The design is one long running task (hours-long) with thousands of sequential calls to various libraries. I currently have a method of pausing this long-running task, that I would first like to discuss before asking my question.

The flow of control for the pause will work as follows:

1. The user/operator clicks on a *pause* button.
2. A `ManualResetEvent` is `Set`.
3. The *running task* (described in first paragraph) will observe the `ManualResetEvent` and stops in its tracks.

The *task* might be some sequential looking thing such as...

```
/// <summary>
/// Some task that calls three wrapped library
/// methods.
/// </summary>
public void MyTaskMethod()
{
    // perform some library methods...
    WrappedLibraryMethodOne();
    WrappedLibraryMethodTwo();
    WrappedLibraryMethodThree();
}
```

The pausing methodology involves the following, wrapping the library methods in order to observe a `ManualResetEvent` as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wraps a library method call, and also checks
/// to see if we're paused.
/// </summary>
public void WrappedLibraryMethodOne()
{
    // 1. Check if we should pause here.
    this.pause.WaitOne();

    // 2. Call the library method.
    this.myLibrary.LibraryMethod();
}
```

Note, that the `ManualResetEvent`s do not adhere to any timeout. Additionally, all of the `WrappedLibraryMethod`s look like this (hence the DRY-thing).

My problem with using this method, is that now I have to wrap all of my library methods. This almost becomes a DRY problem, where I am wrapping every single method that comes along.

**Question**

This way of doing things does work, and I *don't* have a huge issue with the fact that I am only creating an illusion of concurrency. However, should I try and stream-line this somehow?

Comment: I think we need a bit more information. Why do you need to wait or is it 'hit any key to continue'-pausing, for how long do you need to wait, is there any locking mechanism involved, does `WaitOne()` wait a set time or until an event has occured (has someone hit the any key) etc. You mention concurrency is there a reason you don't use threads?

Comment: @Bent I do state that I use a task... So I'm not sure where you're going with that... I'll do my best to add some more information.

Comment: @Bent There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you have a long list of methods that should be called sequentially.

But you would like to be able to pause the execution between each call to a method, but you do not now where beforehand.

An algorithm like this might do the trick

```
public void MyTaskMethod()
{
    List methodObjList = GetListOfMethodObjs();

    foreach(var item in methodObjList)
    {
        this.pause.WaitOne();

        item.method();
    }
}
```